# Convert a char keycode to byte IBM AT-Style Keyboard in c#

Tags: c#, styles, at-command, keycode

I have to read a keycode from keyEventArgs in c# (e.keyCode from KeyDown event) and parse it to IBM AT-Style KeyCode,
(for instance 'a' character key code is 65 but in IBM AT-Style keyboard is 30) anyone knows how can i parse it?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: **Never** do this yourself, the character produced by a virtual key depends on the user's keyboard layout.  Which can be *very* different from yours.  Always use the KeyPressed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are getting at but could it possible be solved with a dictionary?

```
var keyToIBMATCode = new Dictionary<Keys, int> 
{
        { Keys.Q, 16 },
        { Keys.W, 17 },
        { Keys.E, 18 },
        { Keys.R, 19 },
        { Keys.T, 20 },
        { Keys.Y, 21 },
        { Keys.U, 22 },
        { Keys.I, 23 },
        { Keys.O, 24 },
        { Keys.P, 25 },
        { Keys.A, 30 },
        { Keys.S, 31 },
        { Keys.D, 32 },
        { Keys.F, 33 },
        { Keys.G, 34 },
        { Keys.H, 35 },
};

int IBMCode = keyToIBMATCode[Keys.A];
```